# how to change stylesheets using 'onmouseover' and 'onclick' events?

Tags: javascript

I want to change the style sheets permanently when function for 'onclick' event is called.. and 'onmouseover' event would simply change the style sheet as long as the cursor stays on the button..

In my code, Functions for the first two events work perfectly fine..but the 'onclick' event's function doesn't work at all.. 
can anyone tell where i'm doing wrong?
n how can i make it work?

here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css//main.css" >

<script>


function m1()
  {

 document.getElementById("theme").href= "style1.css"; 
}

function o1(){
document.getElementById("theme").href= "css//main.css";
            }

function c1()
  {

document.getElementById("theme").href="style1.css";
}   
     </script>  
</head>
<body>
  <div id="menu">
                <ul id="br">
                    <li> SELECT THEME
                        <ul id="dp">
                            <li><button id="b1" onMouseOver="m1()" onMouseOut="o1()" onClick="c1()" >Style 1</button></li>
                            <li><button id="b2">Style 2</button></li>
                            <li><button id="b3">Style 3</button></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

m1() and c1() load the same stylesheet. When you mouseover the button and click, the two events are fired. I'm not sure about the order of the fired events; however, you should put a console.log in each function to see which is called.

```
function c1(){
    document.getElementById("theme").href="style1.css";
    console.log("On Click");    
}
```